# activeClassName not working in react router NavLink after page redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have react router `NavLinks` in my app. One of them is below:

```js
<NavLink exact to = {{pathname: "/", state: {genreId: 0}}} activeClassName = "active-menu" > Movies </NavLink>
```

In the `Router`, i am redirecting from `/` to `/movies/all`. The problem is after redirecting, the `activeClassName` no longer works. The other routes not redirected are fine. How can i make the `activeClassName` work with redirected path?

Comment: This will redirect you to path `/` not `/movies/all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `exact` from `NavLink` with `exact` the `activeClassName` will be applied only if the location is matched exactly.

Note - Make sure the current location matches the pathname in NavLink for `activeClassName` to work. Also, if `exact` is removed from `/movies` then it will be active for sub paths like `/movies/all`.

You can read more [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool)

Comment: Well removing `exact` alters the behavior of `activeClassName`. It maintains `/` path as active even after navigating to another page.

Comment: 1. The example in your question will route to "/". 2. Do not remove exact from '/' else it will pick up 'active css' along with the current active route. 3. Eg- If you just have a menu item with pathname: "/movies" then by removing exact from its Navlink, you will see it being highlighted even for "/movies/all". 4. Eg - if you have menu item with both '/movies' and '/movies/all' then you will have to add exact to '/movies' so that it doesn't get highlighted when /movies/all is active. Tweak 'exact' to see what fits, if this doesn't resolve please post a detailed code / sandbox

Comment: Thanks. I realise my `NavLink`'s `to` attribute should be the `pathnname` i am redirecting to after hitting the root path `/`. Instead of `<NavLink to = "/"> Movies </NavLink>` and then redirecting at `<Route pathname = "/" render = { () => <Redirect to = "/movies" /> } /> `,  `<NavLink to = "/"> Movies </NavLink>`  should have been `<NavLink to = "/movies"> Movies </NavLink> ` for `activeClassName` to work. Perhaps edit your answer to include that. Someone might run into  similar problem.